# Disable Bluetooth by default in Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, bluetooth

Whenever I turn on my laptop, the Bluetooth applet shows up on the system tray, and Bluetooth is enabled. I rarely ever use it however, and I'd like it to be disabled by default, to avoid battery consumption.

Is there a way for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These [instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingProgramToSessionStartup#To%20stop%20an%20application%20from%20running%20at%20startup) will show you how to stop a program loading during start up, but this does not completely disable bluetooth.

To disable bluetooth, try [these scripts](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1381674) at the Ubuntuforums.

Comment: I believe this doesn't disable Bluetooth - just prevents the applet from starting.

Comment: Sathya is right. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works on my Ubuntu 12.04 and I guess it also depends on the bluetooth stack the distribution is using. The following two commands are used to soft block/unblock the bluetooth. They are in sync with the Blueman Applet. I haven't tested other applets.

`sudo rfkill block bluetooth`

`sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth`

You can check the current status of your devices with:
`rfkill list`